# symfony adding repository function before rendering base.html.twig

Tags: symfony, templates, controller, twig, repository

In Symfony 3.4, base.html.twig I have a navbar showing number of the current user's messages. I use a repository entity function to do this. This function must be call every time when template base.html.twig is rendering but I don't want to put this function in all controllers how to do this by event listener before rendering base.html.twig? Override base controller ?

```
base.html.twig :
  ....
  {{ include top_bar_nav.html.twig }}
  ....
```

Comment: Since this is strictly for rendering then your first choice should probably be to write a custom twig extension: https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html

Comment: I would say yes By an event listener before rendering base.html.twig. It seems you are french. so take a look here at the openclassroom tutorial. This page of the tutorial seems to be exactly about what you are needing. https://openclassrooms.com/courses/developpez-votre-site-web-avec-le-framework-symfony2/le-gestionnaire-d-evenements-de-symfony2

Comment: yes i'm french, and yes openclassrooms is very good but i didn't find the way for my problem. The documentation is so big and i starting with symfony.

Answer (score 1):

A custom Twig extension is the correct way:

example in twig:

```
{{ number_of_current_users() }}
```

create twig extension like this:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Twig;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class UserExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    /**
     * @var EntityRepository
     */
    private $userRepository;

    /**
     * @param EntityRepository $repository
     */
    public function __construct(EntityRepository $repository)
    {
        $this->userRepository = $repository;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction('number_of_current_users', array($this, 'numberOfCurrentUsers')),
        );
    }

    /**
     * @param $sku
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function numberOfCurrentUsers()
    {
        return $this->userRepository->getNumberOfCurrentUsers();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }
}
```

and register it like this:

```
app.twig.users:
    class: AppBundle\Twig\UserExtension
    arguments: ['INJECT YOUR USER REPOSITORY HERE']
    public: false
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

Comment: thanks for your good solution, reactivity and sample code ! in the same time i'm interrogate to simply do a controller for topbar and not use include but render controller in twig template explain here : https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html. What do you think about ?

Comment: your solution is fine too, think about ESI includes: http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/http_cache/esi.html

Comment: ESI is cool but it's a dashboard dynamic application so i think the cache is not often use. I choose controller solution because i do lot of thing inside topbar with user context. good day and thanks again.